# How to define Union polymorphic data structure's instance in Typed Racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

From The [Typed Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html), to define a Union Type, just use `(define-type Some-Type (U Type1 Type2))`.

To define Polymorphic Data Structures, use something like `(define-type (Opt a) (U ...))`.

I want to define a polymorphic binary tree

```
(define-type (Tree a) (U (Leaf a) Node))
(struct (a) Leaf ([val : a]))
(struct Node ([left : Tree] [right : Tree]))
(define t1 (Leaf 5))
(define t2 (Leaf 8))
(define t3 (Node t1 t2))
```

I was wondering why the type of t1 is `Leaf` not `Tree`, and how to make it be a `Tree` ?

```
> t1
- : (Leaf Positive-Byte)
#<Leaf>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
(define-type (Tree a) (U (Leaf a) Node))
```

You're defining `Tree` as a type constructor. You shouldn't think of `Tree` itself as a type, only `(Tree Some-Concrete-Type)` as a type. So rename it to `Treeof`:

```
(define-type (Treeof a) (U (Leaf a) Node))
(struct (a) Leaf ([val : a]))
(struct Node ([left : Treeof] [right : Treeof]))
```

Now the problem is clearer. The node struct expects a `Treeof`, but a tree of what? What you want is this:

```
(define-type (Treeof a) (U (Leaf a) (Node a)))
(struct (a) Leaf ([val : a]))
(struct (a) Node ([left : (Treeof a)] [right : (Treeof a)]))
```

Now your example works:

```
#lang typed/racket
(define-type (Treeof a) (U (Leaf a) (Node a)))
(struct (a) Leaf ([val : a]))
(struct (a) Node ([left : (Treeof a)] [right : (Treeof a)]))
(define t1 (Leaf 5))
(define t2 (Leaf 8))
(define t3 (Node t1 t2))
```

Comment: When I define something like `(define t3
  (Node
   (Leaf 3)
   (Node
    (Leaf 5)
    (Leaf 8))))` , there's a type error.

Comment: Hm. That works for me. What version of racket are you using? Anyway you might be able to fix it by adding an explicit type annotation or using `inst`. Does `(: t3 : (Treeof Integer))
(define t3 (Node (Leaf 3) (Node (Leaf 5) (Leaf 8))))` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the reference about subtyping (https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html#%28part._.Subtyping%29). Basically, when you use the union type, Racket doesn't destruct old types. For example, you could define a type `(U String Number)`, but `String` and `Number` would still be usable. `1` would still be recognized as `Number`, but you can use it in any places that expects `(U String Number)` because `Number` is a subtype of `(U String Number)`.

Similarly, `t1` is a `Leaf`, so there's nothing wrong that Racket reports that `t1` is a `Leaf`. However, `Leaf` is a subtype of `Tree`, so `t1` could be used in places where `Tree` is expected.